# querySelector не валидный селектор

Tags: javascript

querySelector ругается на невалидный параметр "button:clear" - как я понимаю скорее всего из за двоеточие. Как это можно исправить?

```
{

let elem = document.querySelector("button:clear");

console.log(elem);
   
}
```

---

```
<button data-t="button:clear" data-type="phone" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear" autocomplete="off">
::before>
<span class="Button2-Text">Кнопка</span></button>
::after>
</button>
```

Comment: убрать `:clear`

Comment: А что ты пытаешься выбрать? Покажи html

Comment: @Alexey Ten, добавил в описание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для доступа к data-атрибутам используется следующий синтаксис `querySelector('[data-t="atribute"]')`

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('[data-t="button:clear"]');

console.log(elem);
```

```html
<button data-t="button:clear" data-type="phone" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear" autocomplete="off">
<span class="Button2-Text">Кнопка</span></button>
</button>
```